# Using an objective c library (pop) with the swift package manager

Tags: objective-c, swift, swift-package-manager

I'm trying to migrate a project from Cocoapods to SPM and there is one dependency – pop framework – that I can't make work with SPM.

I've tried to compile it into xcframework and use it as a binaryTarget in SPM but it didn't work. This framework seems to be only visible from objective c projects.

These are the commands I used to make xcframework:

```sh
xcodebuild archive -scheme pop-ios-framework -archivePath pop-iphoneos.xcarchive -sdk iphoneos SKIP_INSTALL=NO BUILD_LIBRARY_FOR_DISTRIBUTION=YES

xcodebuild archive -scheme pop-ios-framework -archivePath pop-iphonesimulator.xcarchive -sdk iphonesimulator SKIP_INSTALL=NO BUILD_LIBRARY_FOR_DISTRIBUTION=YES

xcodebuild -create-xcframework -framework pop-iphoneos.xcarchive/Products/Library/Frameworks/pop.framework -framework pop-iphonesimulator.xcarchive/Products/Library/Frameworks/pop.framework -output pop.xcframework
```

and this is how I imported this project to my package:

```swift
targets: [
        .binaryTarget(name: "pop", path: "pop.xcframework"),
        .target(
            name: "...",
            dependencies: [... "SnapKit", "pop"],
            path: "Sources",
            resources: [
                ...
            ]
        ),
    ]
```

The package compiles and even allows writing `import pop`. However, it doesn't see any of the classes defined inside the framework.

Answer (score 0):

So, the problem was that I forgot to set Skip Install to No and Build Libraries for Distribution to YES. I thought that the eponymous params at the end of the commands will override these options.